# How to connect and configure web service to Soap UI, Mysql Workbench, Web service server All Together

Tags: mysql, web-services, testing, mysql-workbench, soapui

I have one Soap WSDL and when I added in SoapUi tool, and I also created the same database in my SQL workbench, but I do not know how to connect the database to Soap Ui request

1. Added WSDL in Soap UI
2. added database in MySQL workbench
3. set all path and the home path to run web services
4. I run the server from Cmd, it is running successfully
5. But when I hit any Add or any Request in Soap UI
6. Server stopped in cmd and shows some connection problem

Give me some points How to configure web services, Mysql workbench, Soap UI, Webservices server all together

```
[INFO] Listening on port 8082
[INFO] [SimpleAxisServer] Started
[SimpleAxisServer] Started
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentClassLoader@3e57cd70
3306
com.sample.reservation.exception.StorageException: Can not get the data 
   base conneciton
    at 
   com.sample.reservation.database.Storage.getConnection(Storage.java:212)
    at 
com.sample.reservation.database.Storage.getEmployeeDetails(Storage.java:89)
    at com.sample.reservation.database.Storage.addEmployee(Storage.java:34)
    atcom.sample.reservation.EmployeeManagementService.addEmployee(EmployeeManagementService.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPWorker.service(HTTPWorker.java:307)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.AxisHttpService.doService(AxisHttpService.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.AxisHttpService.handleRequest(AxisHttpService.java:187)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.HttpServiceProcessor.run(HttpServiceProcessor.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:923)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1715)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1244)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2397)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2430)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2215)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:813)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.sample.reservation.database.Storage.getConnection(Storage.java:206)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [when i try to request using soap ui, theweb services server will give me error of databse connetivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56642595/when-i-try-to-request-using-soap-ui-theweb-services-server-will-give-me-error-o)

Comment: Your question is very unclear what you are asking, but it certainly seems like a duplicate of the same question you asked a month ago. Please have a careful read through [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @SiKing yes you are right, but there is no solution found out on that also

Comment: Please do not spam the site. Have a ready through the links and improve your original question.